# Python how to continue read output even an error occurred

Tags: python, arduino

I have a function to read output stored on Arduino. The output looks like this:

```
['stopped','15.00','25.44','40.5','nan','off','off','on','50.00','yes','on','45']
['version1.0']
['3.0','0.1']
```

The first line includes temperatures at different places, and I need the fourth one. The second line is meaningless, but I need its command to keep the device running. The third line is position and force.
I need to keep sending command to the device in oder to maintain the heaters on, or the device will automatically shut down if no command within 10s. Therefore, I add a command

```
ser.write(b"y\n")
```

The function:

```
def read_output(ser, verbose=True):
    position = []
    force = []
    temp = []
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        line = ser.readline().strip()
        line = ''.join(line.decode()[1:-1])
        line = line.split(' ')
        ser.write(b"y\n") #meaningless command print "version1.0"
        print(line)
        if verbose:
            print(line)
        if len(line) == 2:
            position += [float(line[0])]
            force += [float(line[1])]
        if len(line) == 12:
            temp += [float(line[3])]
            if int(float(line[3])) > 50 
               break
        time.sleep(0.001) # no busy-wait, reduce CPU
    return position, force, temp
```

I will collect data by `p, f, temp = read_output(ser)` and save them in csv at the end.
The code sometimes will be interrupted by misplaced output and with an error like this

```
['version1.0<3.0','0.1']
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'version1.0<3.0'
```

It looks like the second and the third line overlap. I guess this could be due to that `['version1.0']` and position&force outputs `['3.0','1.0']` were printout at the same time.

If this happens, I cannot get the output. Can anyone help me skip this error and continue running the code?

Comment: "Could anyone suggest what the problem could be?" Well, it seems as though `ser.readline()` sometimes gives you data that looks different from what you expected. Did you try to reason through what causes the weird `version1.0<3.0` element to appear? Did you try to check what the original data is, in cases where the happens? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: "Also, could anyone suggest" Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I found the reason and edited my questions.